# replace parts of an xpath with a string taken from a file

Tags: string, xpath

I have rather longish xpath construction with appears several times in an xsl stylesheet.

Of course, this is mangeable per search and replace within the editor, but I wonder, if there is a better solution.

I thought of putting the hole xpath construction into an extern file (lets call it file.xml) like this

```
<ROOT>
<xpath>main_file_root/part2/parts[@xml:id=$a_variable]/@ref</xpath>
</ROOT>
```

and then "re-cycling" this string (via doc('file.xml')/ROOT/xpath ) as part of an xpath expression.

Is this possible?

Is there any xpath magic telling the processor "this string is actually an xpath construction, process it like any other xpath expression"?
(So that in this case the xslt processor would actually take the content of 'main_file_root/part2/parts[@xml:id=$a_variable]/@ref')

I doubt it and I didn't find anything alike, but I thought I give it a try here. It could be very usefull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have rather longish xpath construction with appears several times in an xsl stylesheet.

Given you're referring to the `doc` function I'll assume you're using an XSLT 2.0 processor.  In that case the simplest solution may be to define a custom function within the stylesheet

```
<xsl:function name="local:getref" as="attribute()">
  <xsl:param name="a_variable" />
  <xsl:sequence select="main_file_root/part2/parts[@xml:id=$a_variable]/@ref" />
</xsl:function>
```

(you'll need to add something like `xmlns:local="urn:local-functions"` to the `xsl:stylesheet` tag).

You can then call this function from other expressions as required

```
<xsl:value-of select="local:getref('someId')" />
```

Or it may be more efficient in this specific case to define a key

```
<xsl:key name="partsById" match="main_file_root/part2/parts" use="@xml:id" />
```

and then use `key('partsById', 'someId')/@ref` in the function definition (or just use it directly if you think it's concise enough now).

Comment: Of course not what I was looking for, but thank you very much! Did learn a lot!